# How to transform a list of lists like [1, [2, 3, 4], 5 ] to a list [[1,2,5], [1,3,5], [1,4,5]] in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm just starting with Python and trying to find a general solution to transform a list of lists [1, [2, 3, 4], 5 ]  to a list [[1,2,5], [1,3,5], [1,4,5]] in Python.

I've tried creating some dynamic lists but not getting what i want, not even for this simple list in the example. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
inter_l = []
aba = []
v = [1, [2, 3], 4, 5, 6]
g = globals()

for elem in v:
    if isinstance(elem, (list,)):
        l_ln = len(elem)
        indx = v.index(elem)
        for i in range(0, l_ln):
            g['depth_{0}'.format(i)] = [elem[i]]
            inter_l.append(list(g['depth_{0}'.format(i)]))

    else:
        aba.append(elem)

t = aba.extend(inter_l)
w = aba.extend(inter_l)
print(v)
print(aba)
print(inter_l)
```

> > > [1, [2, 3], 4, 5, 6]
> > >       [1, 4, 5, 6, [2], [3], [2], [3]]
> > >       [[2], [3]]

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? give more examples and expected outputs

Comment: What would you expect from `[1, [2, 3, 4,5], 6,[7,8,9] ]`?

Comment: @dawg and @Tobey -the end result should be a combination of the inner lists + the single elements. From [1, [2, 3, 4,5], 6,[7,8,9] ]  i would expect: `[1,2,6,7]
[1,2,6,8]
[1,2,6,9]
[1,3,6,7]
[1,3,6,8]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to leverage [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function, but since it expects iterables as its inputs, the input would have to be transformed a little. One way to achieve this would be something like this:

```
transformed = [e if isinstance(e, list) else [e] for e in v]
```

which converts all non-list elements into lists and then pass this `transformed` input to `product`:

```
list(itertools.product(*transformed))
```

Note, that `*` in front of `transformed` expands `transformed` list into positional arguments, so that instead of a single argument of type `list`, a list of its elements is passed instead.

The entire pipeline looks something like this:

```
>>> v = [1, [2, 3, 4], 5]
>>> t = [e if isinstance(e, list) else [e] for e in v]
>>> list(itertools.product(*t))
[(1, 2, 5), (1, 3, 5), (1, 4, 5)]
```

Comment: much appreciated, your solution is very elegant, it looks it does what I need. I have to master the itertools module, a lot of interesting functions in there.

Comment: yes, `itertools` is full of super useful functions. Highly recommended :)